# Firebase Closed Funnels With Parameters

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I have seen various Firebase closed funnel [examples](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-do-i-create-a-closed-funnel-in-google-analytics-for-firebase-using-bigquery-6eb2645917e1) on the Internet, but non of them are at the parameter-level.

**Question:**

- I would like to create a closed user funnel based on Firebase event parameter values.
- More specifically, I would like to create a closed user funnel based on the following 3 funnel steps:

  - `first_open` (user opens app for the very first time)
  - `Tutorial_LessonStarted` with parameter-key `LessonNumber` and parameter-value `1`
  - `Tutorial_LessonStarted` with parameter-key `LessonNumber` and parameter-value `2`

**(UPDATE) I moved my original test-query to the answer-section.**

Comment: Well, at least part of the problem is that you've got `e0.event_timestamp > e1_ts`, which will probably never be true if that e0 event is `first_open`. You probably meant to use `<`

Comment: I updated my code. Please view the answer-section below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    e0.event_date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT e0.user_pseudo_id) AS step1_firstOpeners,
    COUNT(DISTINCT e1_user) AS step2_lesson1Started,
    COUNT(DISTINCT e2_user) AS step3_lesson2Started
FROM `projectID.analytics_XXXX.events_*` AS e0
LEFT JOIN (SELECT
                event_name AS e1_eventname,
                e.user_pseudo_id AS e1_user,
                event_timestamp AS e1_ts
           FROM `projectID.analytics_XXXX.events_*` AS e, UNNEST(e.event_params) as eventparams
           WHERE platform = "ANDROID"
                AND event_name = "Tutorial_LessonStarted"
                AND eventparams.key = "LessonNumber"
                AND eventparams.value.string_value  = "1")
    ON e0.user_pseudo_id = e1_user AND e0.event_timestamp < e1_ts AND e1_eventname = "Tutorial_LessonStarted"
LEFT JOIN (SELECT 
                event_name AS e2_eventname,
                e.user_pseudo_id AS e2_user, 
                event_timestamp AS e2_ts
           FROM `projectID.analytics_XXXX.events_*` AS e, UNNEST(e.event_params) as eventparams
           WHERE platform = "ANDROID"
                AND event_name = "Tutorial_LessonStarted" 
                AND eventparams.key = "LessonNumber"
                AND eventparams.value.string_value  = "2")
    ON e1_user = e2_user AND e2_ts > e1_ts AND e2_eventname = "Tutorial_LessonStarted" 

WHERE 
    e0.event_name = 'first_open' 
    AND user_first_touch_timestamp >= 1541808000000000 AND user_first_touch_timestamp < 1541894400000000 -- 10 November 2018
    AND _TABLE_SUFFIX = '20181110'
AND platform = "ANDROID"
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```